# What is the best way to add some space after Bootstrap navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The following code displays a navbar always on the top of the page.
I need the second container (content) to be positioned at the end of the navbar and not under it.
At the moment second container is under the navbar.

I could add some empty space on the top of the content are, but I am not sure it is a good approach. 
Any idea how to solve it?

[image]

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                    <div class="container">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I would need something like this, some space after the navbar http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

Comment: Just add `margin-top: 75px` (or whatever value works) to the `body` element (or the `div` underneath your navbar).

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like more an hack. I would be interested to use bootstramp int he proper way.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

***Updated 2018***

**Bootstrap 3**

According to the Bootstrap docs (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top) you should use `padding-top` on the body..

> "The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add
>   padding to the top of the . Try out your own values or use our
>   snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high."

```
body { padding-top: 70px; }
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/Ob3Bajkv1f

---

**Bootstrap 4**

Padding is also recommended for the `fixed-top` Navbar in Bootstrap 4 to prevent content hiding at the top of the body. You can add custom CSS for `padding-top` or use the `pt-5` utility class on the body tag:

`<body class="pt-5"></body>`

Answer (score 10):

You would need some CSS like this:

```
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Or like this:

```
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Make sure you only use what you need,

Answer (score 1):

Just add `margin-top: 50px;` to the underlaying container.

`50px` has to be the height of your navbar.

Answer (score 0):

You may don't want to hardcode the `padding-top` value in your CSS, since it depends on the navbar's height.

Here's a dynamic solution with JavaScript:

```js
let additionalPadding = 5; // 5px
function updatePaddingTop() {
    $("body").css({
        "padding-top" : $(".navbar").outerHeight() + additionalPadding
    });
}
$(document).ready(() => updatePaddingTop())
```

Also, if your navbox could change size (for example, on window's resize), you may want to detect such a change and re-apply the fix:

```js
var observer = new ResizeObserver(() => {
    updatePaddingTop();
}).observe($(".navbar")[0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this issue using the following code.

```
  <div class="container">
        <!-- navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">KanbanBoard</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Boards</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">User</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <!-- boards -->
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This question is about making room for a `navbar-fixed-top` nav, which your example does not use - so it isn't approaching the problem being asked about.