# Bootstrap nav bar has no spacing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to set up a simple site with bootstrap. I set up a nav bar and some cards however the cards are stuck to the top like there's no nav bar. In the boostrap docs it says that the navbar overlays any content I already have.

The problem is that I can't get any spacing between my cards and nav bar.
[image]

index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Purchase</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Media</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Feedback</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login/Register</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```css
body {
    background-color: #121212;
}
```

Comment: What is your desired outcome?

Comment: For me to be able to change the cards spacing from the navbar (maybe like 30px of space inbetween them)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to add some space after Bootstrap navbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867846/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-some-space-after-bootstrap-navbar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add top padding (e.g., `pt-5`) or top margin (e.g., `mt-5`) to the cards' `container`:

```html
<div class="container mt-5">
```

[image: container with mt-5]

```css
body {
  background-color: #121212;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Purchase</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Media</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Feedback</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login/Register</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```